# Since instead of when

Tags: word-choice

I think  sentence A is wrong with "since". Should I use "when" instead? If I use "since" can I use it this way: "I have been using the internet since I was a child."

A. "I started using the internet since I was a child."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

“I started using the internet when I was a child,” is correct.

“I started using the internet since I was a child,” is incorrect.

“I have been using the internet since I was a child,” is correct.

Edit: It occurred to me after answering that the word “since” can also be used (mostly casually in my experience) to mean “because”. So with an added comma, sentence A could be correct with a different meaning.

“I started using the internet, since I was a child,” is a valid sentence with the same meaning as, “I started using the internet, because I was a child.”

Comment: “I started using the internet, since I was a child,” is a valid sentence with the same meaning as, “I started using the internet, because I was a child.” - I don't believe anyone would really say that.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey If you mean that people wouldn't say that because it's unlikely someone would start using the internet due to being a child, I agree. If you mean nobody would use since to mean "because", I disagree, since I use it that way and hear it used that way all the time.

Comment: I most definitely do not mean 'nobody would use since to mean "because"'. Using 'since' to mean 'because' it is pretty normal and not particularly casual. Both are causal conjunctions, and 'since' is often considered to be the milder of the two, especially if e.g. the causation is indirect.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was beginning to wonder if it was less common in certain regions and seen as archaic or something. I’ve definitely been surprised common words being specific to my region or not common in other regions before.